# Can I receive Wi-Fi with a router (TP-Link Archer AX55 or AX3000 for example) and then send it through wifi on a new SSID?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, home-networking, wifi-configuration

I've got a boat and there is Wi-Fi access on the harbour. At some places on my boat there is no Wi-Fi because it's a steel ship. There is no LAN cable I can put into my router.

What I wanted to do was: Buy a router and the router will receive the Wi-Fi from the harbour. The router would make a new accesspoint SSID and, in that way, I get Wi-Fi on my ship.

Would this work? And if so, what kind of router features would I need. I was looking at the TP-Link Archer AX55 or AX3000.

Comment: This can be done using a standard router that has repeater options as stated in Romeo's answer below. However, in your specific situation i think you would also benefit from making sure the router has removeable antennas so you can remove the stock antenna and attach a directional "Yagi antenna" to it instead. They are long range 2.4Ghz wifi antennas and can be bought cheap on ebay and amazon. With a long enough cable you can have the yagi antenna mounted on top of the boat and connecting to the repeater inside.

Answer (score 0):

What you need in your case is WiFi repeater. This device repeat the signal and (on some devices) you can make new WiFi network. Of course most of the routers can act also as repeaters, but IMHO the cost will be higher.

I can't see AX55 to be able to act as WiFi repeater. Maybe you can try first with something like [one of this](https://www.tp-link.com/en/home-networking/all-network-expansion/).